# Updating tweets.spam column by joining one or two other tables

Tags: mysql

Consider the following three MySQL tables:

```
tweets                        urls                    tweets_urls
---------------------------   ---------------------   ----------------
tweet_id text          spam   url_id  host     spam   tweet_id  url_id
---------------------------   ---------------------   ----------------
   1     I love cnn.com  0      16    cnn.com    0        1       16
   2     fox.com is fuk  0      17    fox.com    1        2       17
   3     love me!        0                                4       16
   4     blah cnn.com    0
   5     nice fox.com    0
```

I want to update tweets.spam by according to tweets_urls, meaning the output of the query should be

```
tweets
---------------------------
tweet_id text          spam
---------------------------
   1     I love cnn.com  0  <-- tweets_urls tells me tweet_id 1 has url_id 16
   2     fox.com is fuk  1      in it, and the urls-table tells me that url 16
   3     love me!        0      is not spam (spam = 0)
   4     blah cnn.com    0
   5     nice fox.com    1
```

I hope I'm making myself clear. I have been fiddling with it and now have something like this. I know it cannot be correct, but have no idea on how to start over. Do you?

```
UPDATE tweets SET spam = (
  SELECT spam FROM urls
  LEFT JOIN tweets_urls
  WHERE urls.url_id = tweets_urls.url_id
)
```

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your given data, this query returns the result set...

```
SELECT t.tweet_id
     , t.text
     , IFNULL(s.spam,t.spam) AS spam
  FROM tweets t
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT tu.tweet_id, MAX(u.spam) AS spam
           FROM tweets_urls tu
           JOIN urls u ON u.url_id = tu.url_id
          WHERE u.spam = 1
          GROUP BY tu.tweet_id
       ) s
    ON s.tweet_id = t.tweet_id
```

But we've made some assumptions about what should be done when is more than one row in tweets_url for a given tweet_id, or when there is no matching url, etc.

If what you want is for a tweet to to marked as 
"spam=1" whenever that tweet is found to be related to ANY url that is marked as "spam=1", and otherwise, the tweet should be marked as "spam=0"...

This will set the spam column for every row in tweets, based on that rule...

```
UPDATE tweets t
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT tu.tweet_id, MAX(u.spam) AS spam
           FROM tweets_urls tu
           JOIN urls u ON u.url_id = tu.url_id
          WHERE u.spam = 1
          GROUP BY tu.tweet_id
       ) s
    ON s.tweet_id = t.tweet_id
   SET t.spam = IFNULL(s.spam,0)
```

---

If you want to leave the spam column alone (leave it set to whatever it is set to) and ONLY want to update a row where the value is currently set to 0 and should be set to 1, according to the "matching url has spam=1", you could do this:

```
UPDATE tweets t
  JOIN ( SELECT tu.tweet_id
           FROM tweets_urls tu
           JOIN urls u ON u.url_id = tu.url_id
          WHERE u.spam = 1
          GROUP BY tu.tweet_id
       ) s
    ON s.tweet_id = t.tweet_id
   SET t.spam = 1
 WHERE t.spam = 0
```

Note that predicate on the tweets table, we will ONLY be updating rows that have spam currently set to zero. And note that we don't need to reference the value of the spam column from the urls table, we're already testing that it's equal to 1, so we can use a literal 1 in the assignment of the value to the tweets.spam column. Also note that we are doing an INNER JOIN (rather than a LEFT OUTER JOIN), so, again, we will only be updating rows that will be assigned a value of 1.

---

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if tweets-table has a row with text NOT containing a URL matching any url from the urls-table, tweets.spam is set to zero (0)? It was my idea it would then be just left alone, because tweets.spam is in that case already set to 0 (see default table where tweets.spam = 0 for all rows already)

Comment: @Pr0no: yes. I've updated my answer, adding another statement that updates ONLY rows that are currently spam=0 which should be set to spam=1 (according to the matching url with spam=1). Whichever works best for you. That's why I was careful to explain what that original query was doing, setting spam on EVERY row in tweets. In MySQL, an update that assigns the same value that is currently there doesn't really modify the row. (This is unlike other databases such as Oracle which record the assignment of the same value as a change.)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to relate the subselect back to the `tweets` table and the `ON` clause in your join:

```
UPDATE tweets SET spam = (
  SELECT spam FROM urls
  LEFT JOIN tweets_urls ON urls.url_id = tweets_urls.url_id
  WHERE tweets_urls.tweet_id = tweets.tweet_id
)
```

You also have not defined what to do in the case that:

- There is no entry in `tweets_urls` for the tweet_id
- There are multiple entries in `tweets_urls` for the tweet_id

Finally, as a side note, are you *sure* you want to be UPDATING like this? It sounds more like something you want to produce using a view or stored procedure - unless `urls` and `tweets_urls` are just tables you've added now to help populate the `tweets` table and then will drop later.

Comment: don't you need limit 1? (just in case?)

Comment: @jcho360 Yes, if that's the desired behavior. Also not sure what to do with the NULLs for tweet_ids 3 and 5.

Comment: lol, that's the problem when we don't use sqlfiddle to everybody see the result

Comment: To answer your questions: in case there is no entry in `tweets_urls` for a certain tweet_id, then tweets.spam should just be left to 0 (as is the case in the default situation). Second, there are * never * multiple entries in tweets_urls for every tweet_id. In other words: at most, any tweet only contains 1 URL. I hope this helps and thanks for you help until now :-)

Comment: Then you should add a `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tweets_urls where tweets_urls.tweet_id = tweets.tweet_id)` clause to the end of it to make sure you only update rows which have an entry in `tweets_urls`. Go play around with the sqlfiddle I set up if you'd like to see what I mean about NULLs.

Comment: Please refer to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02095/3 ... it does not catch tweet_id 5 in the output...any idea as to why not?

Comment: There's no tweet_id 5 in `tweets_urls`. Looking at your sample output again, maybe you meant to have a row (5,17) in `tweets_urls`?